# Ekiga softphone shows as "registered" -- but is it actually?

Tags: networking, tcpip, voip, sip, asterisk

Is Ekiga actually registered? How would I know?

I think Ekiga connects, or at least it says "registered":

[image: ekiga]

But, when I exit Ekiga, and use SFLphone, it fails to register:

[image: sflphone]

While `sipsak` shows a 200 OK for `tleilax`:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ sudo sipsak -vv -s sip:102@tleilax -m "hi"
No SRV record: _sip._tcp.tleilax
No SRV record: _sip._udp.tleilax
using A record: tleilax
Max-Forwards set to 0

message received:
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 127.0.1.1:46481;branch=z9hG4bK.6357e66e;alias;received=192.168.1.3;rport=46481
From: sip:sipsak@127.0.1.1:46481;tag=134701bd
To: sip:102@tleilax;tag=as7588f973
Call-ID: 323420605@127.0.1.1
CSeq: 1 OPTIONS
Server: Asterisk PBX 1.8.29.0-vici
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:192.168.1.2:5060>
Accept: application/sdp
Content-Length: 0



** reply received after 0.752 ms **
   SIP/2.0 200 OK
   final received
thufir@doge:~$
```

there are too many hops for outside connectivity:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ sudo sipsak -vv -s sip:thufir@ekiga.net -m "hi"
No SRV record: _sip._tcp.ekiga.net
No SRV record: _sip._udp.ekiga.net
using A record: ekiga.net
Max-Forwards set to 0

message received:
SIP/2.0 483 Too Many Hops
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.3:44370;branch=z9hG4bK.6f1c2f33;rport=44370;alias;received=96.48.128.162
From: sip:sipsak@127.0.1.1:44370;tag=981cae4
To: sip:thufir@ekiga.net;tag=c64e1f832a41ec1c1f4e5673ac5b80f6.bf6c
Call-ID: 159501028@127.0.1.1
CSeq: 1 OPTIONS
Server: Kamailio (1.5.3-notls (i386/linux))
Content-Length: 0



** reply received after 161.445 ms **
   SIP/2.0 483 Too Many Hops
   final received
thufir@doge:~$
```

This is in the context of trying to use [SIPp as a diagnostic tool](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186041/sipp-hello-world-message-to-asterisk) with a less than optimal [network configuration](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186038/asterisk-network-topology-kiss).